# Is it possible to create categories that are available in a Wordpress theme by default?

Tags: wordpress, categories

Is there a way of having categories available right after installing a theme.

For instance, if a theme post content to a loop which retrieves posts with the category "Tagline". Is there a way of having the category "Tagline" by default (in the theme)?

(So the end user wouldn't have to create it himself/herself)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using wp_insert_category(); -- see: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_category

You'd probably have to write an init function in functions.php that runs the first time the theme is activated and calls the above function. You'll want to write some error handling that prevents it from being run multiple times, however.